# How to handle work capacity across different teams

Tags: team, time-management, projects

As a software developer with some years of experience, I seem to run into this same issue in one form or another, so I'l generalize it the best I can.

Let's say I'm on 3 teams. Team A has given me enough work to keep me busy if they were my only team. Team B had a project that should have been completed  a while back, but the client won't accept it for one reason or another, so I'm brought back in regularly to handle the client's issues. Team C maintains a legacy system that catches on fire sometimes and I'm called in to help put it out.

All three are important and I have trouble finding someone else to pass the work onto. So, how do I juggle the 3 teams plus all the other business-related responsibilities?

Comment: Are you asking how can you handle your workload? Or are you asking how should the workload be distributed so developers dont end with a task weight of 300%?

Comment: Well, I know how I handle the workload, but I'm looking for how to manage team expectations when I answer to all three teams, but the teams don't interact with one another, so they don't know how my work capacity is divided.

Answer (score 9):

> So, how do I juggle the 3 teams plus all the other business-related
>   responsibilities?

Ask your boss to help you set priorities. Presumably it was your boss that put you on three different teams at the same time.

Some bosses would prefer 100% of your time dedicated to whichever team asked for your time first, until their project is done. Others would prefer you to split your time equally. Others have their own prioritization method.

> All three are important

Certainly. But it's unlikely that all three are equally important all the time.

Comment: Good answer. Specifically, keep a personal priority list in order. Ask your boss to look at it weekly and let you know if you should adjust your priorities. When your "customers" grumble, ask your boss to help you respond.

Answer (score 2):

TBH, unless you are your own manager, this is an issue for your manager to figure out. Talk to him/her about your tasks, commitments, and anything else that's relevant. Then ask them to prioritize your tasks and commitments. Keep track of what you work on and for how long. Present this information to your manager if people start questioning your time allocation.

Comment: +1 : About 90% of workplace.stackexchange questions can be answered by "speak with your manager".

Answer (score 1):

It's understandable that all 3 are important, and it's hard to prioritize. This happens a lot in the workplace. I would give you these options for a solution.

- Ask your supervisor which has the **highest** priority or the greatest impact for the company and focus on that.
- Decide if you should start with the simple tasks first to free up additional time.
- Schedule your day. Start your morning off with the high priority project (greatest productivity can be in the morning hours) designate a hard stop time and change tasks.

The best thing to do is the third, in my opinion. That is how I handle my work load.